# Schematic notation conventions

Tags: schematics

I am studying [this](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Demo%20Board%20Schematic/1666asch.pdf) reference design, and see the following 4 connections (only 1 is circled):

[image]

At first glance its telling me to use a large trace and/or multiple traces; but I am not sure as there are no notes. What could this possibly mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means that there are multiple pins on the device to handle high current or for lower inductance.  They are wired together at the same potential.

Comment: ohhhhh.... wow, that was a simpler than I though. http://documentation.renesas.com/doc/products/transistor/r07ds0076ej_rjk0651dpb.pdf shows the symbol :D

Answer (score 3):

It's also a way to create nets into different pads (electrically equivalent in that component) when you transfer the schematic to PCB.

It's not necessarily a way to express the need for a wide trace, as for example, some SMB and coaxial connectors have 4 ground pins but they are not for the sake of current but to ensure a more complete sheilding.

Comment: And some SMT connectors have extra pins for mechanical strength.